# node.js redis and how to use promise when using a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, promise, q

I have an Express route like this in an node server (file is required):

```
var redis = require('../modules/redis');

module.exports = function (app) {

var redisClient = redis.init();


app.post('/auth/ticket', cors(), function (req, res) {


    var hashes = ['hash1','hash2', 'hash3'];

    var candidates = [];  // An array to collect valid hashes
    var key;  
    // to check each hash against a RedisDB I use a For Loop
    for (key in hashes) {
        var hash = hashes[key];
        console.log("Hash " + hash + "  will be proofed now:");
       //now I try to collect the valid hashes in the candidates array
       if (redisClient.exists(hash) === 1) candidates.push(hash);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(candidates));
});
};
```

Now here is the code of my module which shall manage all the redis requests:

```
exports.init = function () {
Redis = exports.Redis = function () {
    var promiseFactory = require("q").Promise,
        redis = require('promise-redis')(promiseFactory);

    this.client = redis.createClient();
    this.client.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('redis error – ' + client.host + ':' + client.port + ' – ' + err);
    });

Redis.prototype.exists = function (key) {
    this.client.exists(key, function (err, data) {
       return data === 1 ? true : false;
    });
};

return new Redis();
};
```

So what I experience is that the module is able to console.log the results properly. If a hash is valid, it returns true and otherwise false. This works as expected. 
Problem is, that the for-loop continuous the execution without fetching getting the results. I think this is caused by race-conditions.

As you can see, I have started to workout something there with the use of Q and promise-redis in the top of my code:

```
 var promiseFactory = require("q").Promise,
    redis = require('promise-redis')(promiseFactory);

this.client = redis.createClient();
```

I like to know, how I make my for-loop (in the Express route) waiting for the results of redisClient.exists(hash) or in other words, to get all valid hashes into my candidates array.

Please help

Comment: You can use your promise libary's `all()` function.  This will look them all up simultaneously and return the results when they are done. Beware though that this could put a large load on Redis if you have a lot to look up.

Comment: this is a in my case, too. I need to lookup between 1 and 12 hashes averagely. And it is a load balanced system. But I don't know how to implement it correctly. I never used promise it in this circumstances.

Comment: Maybe you could give me code example how you would workout the case. Just a step in, so I can develop it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like @brad said, you could use `Q.all`, it would take an array of promises as input and then return an array of results when all the promises are finished:

there is a mistake in your answer:

```
Redis.prototype.exists = function (key) {

return this.client.exists(key)      // CHANGED, you still need to return a promise.
    .then(function (reply) {
        console.log("reply " + reply);
        return (reply);
    })
    .catch(console.log);

};
```

If I understand correctly, what you want is something like

```
exports.init = function () {
Redis = exports.Redis = function () {
    var Q = require("q"),
        promiseFactory = Q.Promise,
        redis = require('promise-redis')(promiseFactory);

    this.client = redis.createClient();
    this.client.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('redis error – ' + client.host + ':' + client.port + ' – ' + err);
    });

Redis.prototype.exists = function (key) {
    return this.client.exists(key).then(function (data) {
       return data === 1 ? true : false;
    });
};

Redis.prototype.getActive = function (arry) {
    var self = this;
    return  Q.all(arry.map(self.exists.bind(self))
            ).then(function(res){
                return arry.filter(function(val, idx){ return res[idx];});
            });
};



return new Redis();
};
```

Comment: Thank you both guys, your answer brought he final enlightenment to the usage of promises :-), awesome.

Comment: But did you also recognize that I outsourced all the reds functions to the module file (1st Codeblock) which requires the promise-redid and builds a factory for Q.

Comment: @gwinger but in second block `Redis.prototype.exists` still uses the node callback way rather than the promise way.

Comment: Your changes seem to be the right way, but in the return:   return  Q.all(arry.map(self.exists.bind(self))   Q is not defined??? Can't understand this. hmm

Comment: ` Q = require("q")` for using Q promise, also `arry.map(self.exists.bind(self)` would return a array of promises, `bind` is for binding the right object for `this` variable in `Redis.exists`, and `Q.all(...)` would make a promise that would wait for all the promises to finish before it continues...

Comment: Great support mido22. We get it to work correctly with your guideline. Very impressive solution. I have to thank you for your engagement.

Answer (score 1):

@ mido22: But did you also recognize that I outsourced all the reds functions to the module file (1st Codeblock) which requires the promise-redid and builds a factory for Q. I changed the code inside the module file to:

```
    Redis.prototype.exists = function (key) {

    this.client.exists(key)
        .then(function (reply) {
            console.log("reply " + reply);
            return (reply);
        })
        .catch(console.log);

    };
```

and this results correctly like the console.log evidently shows.
Your codechange of the for-loop works very well but I think it don't fulfills my needs perfectly. If I could, I would like to have it completely outsourced in to the module file, so that I can use the prototyped method in similar cases from everywhere. Is that possible anyhow?
I see, that it would result in having two promise supported functionalities, if I would create an Instance of Redis Client with promise-redid and Q inside the auth/ticket/ router, too.
like this:

```
var Q = require('q'),
promiseFactory = Q.Promise,
redis = require("promise-redis")(promiseFactory),
client;
```

an then the express route (there are a lot of more routes each in a single file) like in your code.

Do you understand what I mean? Of course your solution will be fine for my needs at all, but a module resolving the job completely could have more elegance if possible so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using with redis, bluebird and typescript:

```
import { RedisClient, createClient, ClientOpts } from "redis";
import { promisifyAll, PromisifyAllOptions } from "bluebird";


export module FMC_Redis {

    export class Redis {
        opt: ClientOpts;
        private rc: RedisClient;
        private rcPromise: any;

        private static _instance: Redis = null;
        public static current(_opt?: ClientOpts): Redis {

            if (!Redis._instance) {
                Redis._instance = new Redis(_opt);
                Redis._instance.redisConnect();
            }
            return Redis._instance;
        }

        public get client(): RedisClient {
            if (!this.rc.connected) throw new Error("There is no connection to Redis DB!");
            return this.rc;
        }

        /******* BLUEBIRD ********/
        public get clientAsync(): any {
            // promisifyAll functions of redisClient 
            // creating new redis client object which contains xxxAsync(..) functions.
            return this.rcPromise = promisifyAll(this.client);
        }

        private constructor(_opt?: ClientOpts) {
            if (Redis._instance) return;

            this.opt = _opt
                ? _opt
                : {
                    host: "127.0.0.1",
                    port: 6379,
                    db: "0"
                };
        }

        public redisConnect(): void {
            this.rc = createClient(this.opt);
            this.rc
                .on("ready", this.onReady)
                .on("end", this.onEnd)
                .on("error", this.onError);
        }

        private onReady(): void { console.log("Redis connection was successfully established." + arguments); }
        private onEnd(): void { console.warn("Redis connection was closed."); }
        private onError(err: any): void { console.error("There is an error: " + err); }


        /****** PROMISE *********/
        // promise redis test
        public getRegularPromise() {
            let rc = this.client;
            return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
                console.warn("> getKeyPromise() ::");
                rc.get("cem", function (err, val) {
                    console.log("DB Response OK.");
                    // if DB generated error:
                    if (err) rej(err);
                    // DB generated result:
                    else res(val);
                });
            });
        }


        /******* ASYNC - AWAIT *******/
        // async - await test function
        public delay(ms) {
            return new Promise<string>((fnResolve, fnReject) => {
                setTimeout(fnResolve("> delay(" + ms + ") > successfull result"), ms);
            });
        }

        public async delayTest() {
            console.log("\n****** delayTest ")
            let a = this.delay(500).then(a => console.log("\t" + a));

            let b = await this.delay(400);
            console.log("\tb::: " + b);
        }

        // async - await function
        public async getKey(key: string) {
            let reply = await this.clientAsync.getAsync("cem");
            return reply.toString();
        }
    }
}

let a = FMC_Redis.Redis.current();
// setTimeout(function () {
//     console.warn(a.client.set("cem", "naber"));
//     console.warn(a.client.get("cem"));
//     console.warn(a.client.keys("cem"));
// }, 1000);

/***** async await test client *****/
a.delayTest();


/** Standart Redis Client test client */
setTimeout(function () {
    a.client.get("cem", function (err, val) {
        console.log("\n****** Standart Redis Client")
        if (err) console.error("\tError: " + err);
        else console.log("\tValue ::" + val);
    });
}, 100)

/***** Using regular Promise with Redis Client > test client *****/
setTimeout(function () {
    a.getRegularPromise().then(function (v) {
        console.log("\n***** Regular Promise with Redis Client")
        console.log("\t> Then ::" + v);
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error("\t> Catch ::" + e);
    });
}, 100);

/***** Using bluebird promisify with Redis Client > test client *****/
setTimeout(function () {
    var header = "\n***** bluebird promisify with Redis Client";
    a.clientAsync.getAsync("cem").then(result => console.log(header + result)).catch(console.error);
}, 100);
```

[image]